authjs v5 error in signIn options returning type is never
'use server'
import { signIn } from "@/auth"

export const SignIn = async (data: any) => {
  const updatedData =  {...data, redirect: false}
  console.log(data)
  
  const signIndata = await signIn("credentials", updatedData)
  
  if(signIndata?.error){
    console.log(signIndata?.error)
  } else{
    return 'ok'
  }
}

and this is what i am doing on other side
i cant access the value signIndata?.error beause signIndata showing the type never
the data i am sending is { email: "sdfss@gmail.com", password: "password123"}
please help me how to solve this
i expected it to console the error if there is error and return "ok" if not error,
so i can do router.push("/admin")

Welcome to stackoverflow, You wrote the code of a server action, all the function SignIn  paths should return a value, you can't simply return in an else statement without returning in the if statement, there's another problem which is you're using type any for data while your data type is predefined (email and password). Second thing is that you did not show the component where you're using the action, which is necessarry to know if the problem is from there, please edit this post to provide these informations.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
